# What does while (true){ mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I've seen this code, and I've no idea what it means.

```
while(true){
    echo "Hello world";
}
```

I know what a while loop is, but what does while(true) mean? How many times will it executed. Is this not an infinite loop?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is an infinite loop.

The explicit version would be

```
while (true == true)
```

Comment: Yep, true will always remain true and not change state so your loop will never end.

Comment: @Ignacio you mean signed vs. unsigned `true`. Those are coming in PHP 7, I'm told

Comment: Not explicit enough. `while (((((true == true) == true) == true) == true) == true){`

Comment: and the inverse: `while (true != false)` and back: `while ((true != false )==true)`

Comment: @stillstanding One would have to add your code to @Ignacio's to be 100% sure. It's because of PHP's weak typing that such checks need to be reinforced a few times for it to be really stable.

Comment: also `while (constant("TRUE"))` and clever variations with `isset`, and btw you need the `===` exact match operator

Comment: you might need to do some rounding and tolerance checking too, in case TRUE returns a float

Comment: Think different: `while(!isset($unsetvariable)){}`

Comment: @stillstanding True. It will do that when the bcmath extension is installed, so one can get fractions of `true`

Comment: @andre: `while (extension_loaded('Core')) {}`

Comment: @stillstanding: lol was thinking something similar... `while(function_exists('function_exists')){}`

Comment: this comment section now qualifies as the "Most Stupid Code Golf"

Comment: @andre you can `continue`, but you can never `break`

Comment: `goto first_comment; // endless loop`

Comment: @stillstanding this comment thread supports PHP 5.2 only. It's my answer, so I get to choose the version. No `goto` on my watch

Comment: I do not see why (true == true) should be more explicit than (true)

Comment: @Marco "explicit" meaning, "human readable so you can understand what the interpreter is doing"

Comment: @Pekka, given that at the end the result is a boolean expression, it seems to me that the expression "true" (the most readable boolean expression possible) is better than "true == true". Using the same approach, If you need the expression false what would you write ? false == true ?

Comment: @Marco `true`, in this context, is not as easy to understand to a novice as `true == true`. `Using the same approach, If you need the expression false what would you write ? false == true?` when explaining to someone how programming works, in this context, yes.

Comment: @FarisRayhan well, it *is* an infinite loop. The script will never terminate and you probably won't see a response.

Answer (score 27):

Although is an infinite loop you can exit it using [break](http://no.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php). It is useful when waiting for something to happen but you don't exactly know the number of iteration that will get you there.

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed (as stated already) an infinite loop and usually contains code which ends itself by using a 'break' / 'exit' statement.

Lots of daemons use this way of having a PHP process continue working until some external situation has changed. (i.e. killing it by removing a .pid file / sending a HUP etc etc)

Answer (score 5):

Please referes to the PHP documentation currently at: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp

> The while loop executes a block of code as long as the specified condition is true.

```
while (expression) {
    statement(s) 
}
```

> The while statement evaluates expression, which must return a boolean value. If the expression evaluates to true, the
>   while statement executes the statement(s) in the while block. The
>   while statement continues testing the expression and executing its
>   block until the expression evaluates to false.

As a consequence, the code:

```
while (true) {
    statement(s)
}
```

will execute the statements indefinitely because "true" is a boolean expression that, as you can expect, is always true.

As already mentioned by @elzo-valugi, this loop can be interrupted using a break (or exit):

```
while (true) {
    statement(s)
    if (condition) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: w3schools is a third-party site hosting educational content, not the php documentation - the official documentation can be found at https://www.php.net (https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php)

Answer (score 3):

It is indeed an infinite loop.